# Making connections in .xib file. Conway & Hillegass book

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

From the Conway & Hillegass book "Big Nerd Ranch Guide, iOS Programming", Chapter 7 "UIViewController".

We create an app with two views, two UIViewControllers. One view and it's UIViewController we made and connected programmatically in previous chapters, another view we should make in the xib file and make necessary connections with the File's Owner. 
Custom view should show a label and a button. Once button is tapped, label should display current time.

The program compile but after pressing the button, label doesn't show current time. 
I suspect my mistake is at the moment when I need to set connections in the xib file with file's owner. 
Here is what I did: 
I control click on the file's owner, choose "Received Actions: showCurrentTime" and drag it to the button. Then choose: "Did end on ending".
I control click on the file's owner, choose "Outlets: timeLabel" and drag it to the label.

Can anyone spot a mistake?

Here is the code:

TimeViewController.h: (UIViewController of custom view)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TimeViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;
}-
(IBAction)showCurrentTime:(id)sender;

@end
```

TimeViewController.m:

```
#import "TimeViewController.h"

@implementation TimeViewController


- (IBAction)showCurrentTime:(id)sender
{
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[timeLabel setText:[formatter stringFromDate:now]];
}

@end
```

HypnoAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "HypnoAppDelegate.h"
#import "HypnosisViewController.h"
#import "TimeViewController.h"

@implementation HypnoAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

//....creating an instance of our UIViewController and setting it as a root view. This is          an instance of custom view we've created programmatically.  
HypnosisViewController *hvc = [[HypnosisViewController alloc] init];

TimeViewController *tvc = [[TimeViewController alloc] init];
[[self window] setRootViewController:tvc];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
} 

@end
```

Comment: did you at least check (via debugger) if showCurrentTime is being called when button is clicked? also '-' sign is missing from showCurrentTime in header file (well it's on top of it now that I see it, though not sure if that can cause the issue).

Comment: Thanks for participating. I found problem in choosing the wrong option for the button. I added answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found mistake while comparing this code with the provided solutions to the book. 
Mistake was made in the .xib file, when making connections with the file's owner. Unfortunately in the book there is no information on how to properly do that.

the mistake was made in choosing wrong action for the button. Instead of choosing "Did end on ending" the option "Touch Up Inside" have to be chosen. 
That fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes, that "Did end on ending" sounded a bit weird to me initially when I read your post ..

Comment: I assumed the most simple move of pressing the button would be the first one from the drop down menu. Alas.